# Convert all nested xml InfoTables into Python dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, xml, parsing

I have this xml (at the bottom of this post). I first get the xml from a URL, https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1067983/000095012320012127/0000950123-20-012127-1653.xml

I then want to parse the the information in each infoTable into a python dictionary.

e.g.

```
holdings_1 = { 'nameOfIssuer': 'BIG COMPANY NAME', etc.}
holdings_2 = { 'nameOfIssuer': 'COMPANY NAME 2', etc.}
```

Right now I'm doing this:

```
import traceback
import urllib3
import xmltodict

url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1067983/000095012320012127/0000950123-20-012127-1653.xml"

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

response = http.request('GET', url)

try:
    data = xmltodict.parse(response.data)
    unordered_dict = dict(data['informationTable'])
except:
    print("Failed to parse xml from response (%s)" % traceback.format_exc())

print(unordered_dict)
```

However, this is making the parent InformationTable the dictionary, and all the child InfoTables are nested inside it as ordered dictionaries. I'm not sure what's the best way to resolve this.

XML for reference:

```
<informationTable xmlns="http://www.sec.gov/edgar/document/thirteenf/informationtable">
    <infoTable>
        <nameOfIssuer>COMPANY NAME</nameOfIssuer>
        <titleOfClass>COM</titleOfClass>
        <cusip>000034324</cusip>
        <value>100</value>
        <shrsOrPrnAmt>
            <sshPrnamt>9000</sshPrnamt>
            <sshPrnamtType>SH</sshPrnamtType>
        </shrsOrPrnAmt>
            <investmentDiscretion>DFND</investmentDiscretion>
            <otherManager>1,2</otherManager>
        <votingAuthority>
            <Sole>10000</Sole>
            <Shared>0</Shared>
            <None>0</None>
        </votingAuthority>
    </infoTable>
    <infoTable>
        <nameOfIssuer>COMPANY NAME 2</nameOfIssuer>
        <titleOfClass>COM</titleOfClass>
        <cusip>020002101</cusip>
        <value>86663</value>
        <shrsOrPrnAmt>
            <sshPrnamt>50000</sshPrnamt>
            <sshPrnamtType>SH</sshPrnamtType>
        </shrsOrPrnAmt>
            <investmentDiscretion>DFND</investmentDiscretion>
            <otherManager>1,2</otherManager>
        <votingAuthority>
            <Sole>10000</Sole>
            <Shared>0</Shared>
            <None>0</None>
        </votingAuthority>
    </infoTable>
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend you change your approach: you have 145 tables in that page so with your approach the `nameOfIssuer`, `titleOfClass` and of the other 15 or so elements and children will appear 145 times. You are probably better off creating a dataframe for each issuer where these appear as columns and the holdings appear as rows.

Comment: Thanks, this was a better idea using Pandas. If you want to chuck this comment into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As much as I like xml (and I like it a lot!) and dictionaries, sometimes for more readablility you have to resort to tables - dataframes, when using python. The xml in the EDGAR filing in the question is an excellent example: it only has 145 entries but 2,467 xml rows! A string like `titleOfClass`which should appear **once** as column header appears 290 times in the xml...

So, yes, a table is a way to go. Normally you would use pandas' `read_html()` but it doesn't work with xml. You could also load the data intro lxml and manually extract the data and convert it into a dataframe. But in this particular case I would use [another library, pandas_read_xml](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-read-xml/), which significantly simplifies the process:

```
import pandas_read_xml as pdx
url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1067983/000095012320012127/0000950123-20-012127-1653.xml'
df = pdx.read_xml(url,['informationTable','infoTable'])

# the next two enties are used to expand these two columns into their components
df2 = pd.json_normalize(df['shrsOrPrnAmt'])
df3 = pd.json_normalize(df['votingAuthority'])

df_list = [df,df2,df3]
to_drop = ['shrsOrPrnAmt','votingAuthority'] # now that we expanded them, we don't these 2 columns anymore
final_df = pd.concat(df_list, axis = 1).drop(to_drop, axis = 1)
final_df
```

The output is your table.

Comment: Very, very soon pandas will have `read_xml` and `to_xml` (in version 1.3.0). See my current [PR](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/39516). All tests passed, awaiting for merge. With `lxml` as parser, XPath 1.0 and XSLT 1.0 supported. All OP would need to do `df = pd.read_xml(url)` since `<infoTable>` is child of root.

Answer (score 1):

Consider parsing the XML response with a compliant DOM library like built-in `etree`. Then, run a list/dict comprehension to build a list of dictionaries for all `<infoTable>` nodes (children and grandchildren). One main issue is XML uses a default namespace that needs to define a prefix in order to parse by named nodes

```py
import traceback
import urllib3
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et  # PYTHON STANDARD LIBRARY
from pprint import pprint           # PYTHON STANDARD LIBRARY

url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1067983/000095012320012127/0000950123-20-012127-1653.xml"

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

response = http.request('GET', url)
doc = et.fromstring(response.data)

nmsp = {"doc": "http://www.sec.gov/edgar/document/thirteenf/informationtable"}

try:
    # MERGE DICT APPROACH (Python 3.5+) OF CHILDREN AND GRANDCHILDREN NODES
    # USE split() TO REMOVE NAMESPACE IN TAG NAME
    data_dicts = [{**{ch.tag.split('}')[1]: ch.text.strip() for ch in el.findall("./*/*")},
                   **{t.tag.split('}')[1]: t.text.strip() for t in el.findall("*")}
                  } for el in doc.findall(".//doc:infoTable", namespaces=nmsp)]
    
except:
    print(f"Failed to parse xml from response ({traceback.format_exc()})")

pprint(len(data_dicts))
# 145

pprint(data_dicts)
```

**Output**

```py
[{'None': '0',
  'Shared': '0',
  'Sole': '21264316',
  'cusip': '00287Y109',
  'investmentDiscretion': 'DFND',
  'nameOfIssuer': 'ABBVIE INC',
  'otherManager': '4,11',
  'shrsOrPrnAmt': '',
  'sshPrnamt': '21264316',
  'sshPrnamtType': 'SH',
  'titleOfClass': 'COM',
  'value': '1862541',
  'votingAuthority': ''},
 {'None': '0',
  'Shared': '0',
  'Sole': '419500',
  'cusip': '023135106',
  'investmentDiscretion': 'DFND',
  'nameOfIssuer': 'AMAZON COM INC',
  'otherManager': '4',
  'shrsOrPrnAmt': '',
  'sshPrnamt': '419500',
  'sshPrnamtType': 'SH',
  'titleOfClass': 'COM',
  'value': '1320892',
  'votingAuthority': ''},
 {'None': '0',
  'Shared': '0',
  'Sole': '113800',
  'cusip': '023135106',
  'investmentDiscretion': 'DFND',
  'nameOfIssuer': 'AMAZON COM INC',
  'otherManager': '4,8,11',
  'shrsOrPrnAmt': '',
  'sshPrnamt': '113800',
  'sshPrnamtType': 'SH',
  'titleOfClass': 'COM',
  'value': '358325',
  'votingAuthority': ''}

...

{'None': '0',
  'Shared': '0',
  'Sole': '1625185',
  'cusip': 'G9001E102',
  'investmentDiscretion': 'DFND',
  'nameOfIssuer': 'LIBERTY LATIN AMERICA LTD',
  'otherManager': '4,8,11',
  'shrsOrPrnAmt': '',
  'sshPrnamt': '1625185',
  'sshPrnamtType': 'SH',
  'titleOfClass': 'COM CL A',
  'value': '13408',
  'votingAuthority': ''},
 {'None': '0',
  'Shared': '0',
  'Sole': '146177',
  'cusip': 'G9001E128',
  'investmentDiscretion': 'DFND',
  'nameOfIssuer': 'LIBERTY LATIN AMERICA LTD',
  'otherManager': '4',
  'shrsOrPrnAmt': '',
  'sshPrnamt': '146177',
  'sshPrnamtType': 'SH',
  'titleOfClass': 'COM CL C',
  'value': '1190',
  'votingAuthority': ''},
 {'None': '0',
  'Shared': '0',
  'Sole': '1284020',
  'cusip': 'G9001E128',
  'investmentDiscretion': 'DFND',
  'nameOfIssuer': 'LIBERTY LATIN AMERICA LTD',
  'otherManager': '4,8,11',
  'shrsOrPrnAmt': '',
  'sshPrnamt': '1284020',
  'sshPrnamtType': 'SH',
  'titleOfClass': 'COM CL C',
  'value': '10452',
  'votingAuthority': ''}]
```